# ng- smart-table using "POST" instead of "GET" for pagination how to add extra parameters in body

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng2-smart-table

I've checked the document and source code for pagination implementation (advanced-example-server.component.ts). And found that the ServerDataSource it used had only implemented pagination via HTTP GET (_sort, _limit, _page, etc parameters expose in URL)..... as my currently project worked on required to use POST to send front-end parameters to back-end Restful APIs using extends to HTTP post call implement, I don't know how to add the extra parameters in pagination request. I Need To pass the request_server to extendsplugin.ts

extendsplugin.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import { ServerDataSource } from 'ng2-smart-table';

    export class PostServerDataSource extends ServerDataSource {

        protected requestElements(): Observable<any> {
            let httpParams = this.createRequesParams();
            return this.http.post(this.conf.endPoint, request_server, { observe: 'response' });
        }

    }
```

anotherComponent.ts

```
swiftListTable() {
    const request_server = JSON.stringify({ "userType": this.currentUser.role, "authName": this.currentUser.username })
    this.source = new PostServerDataSource(this.http,{endPoint: this.service.apiURL + 'swift/pagination', dataKey: 'content', pagerLimitKey:"_limit",
    pagerPageKey:"_page",
    sortDirKey: "pageable",
    sortFieldKey: "pageable",
    totalKey:'totalElements'});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a POST request, your request body can contain a JSON object with as many properties as you like. Thus, you just need to add the extra parameters in your `createRequestParams()` method and return them. See also the [Official Angular Guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request) to better understand how Angular's HttpClient handles POST requests.

Comment: add like this  let httpParams =Object.assign({user:'user', fsdfdsg:'sdgsg' }, this.createRequesParams()) its not working

Comment: No, you simply need to add the required properties inside of your `createRequesParams()` method implementation. Like this: `createRequesParams() {return {user:'user', fsdfdsg:'sdgsg' };}`